# Creating AWS SES SMTP credentials in python2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, python-2.7

I am creating an SES SMTP credentials from my iam accesskey and secretkey. i have referred to this [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/smtp-credentials.html) for creating the SES SMTP credentials

But the code produces different SES SMTP credentials for python2 and python3 but the python3 key is the valid one. how can i get the same key while executing the script with python2
Below is my script which returns accesskey and  SES SMTP cred. Iam getting the IAM accesskey and secretkey from secrets manager

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3

import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
import argparse
import boto3
import json
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def get_secretmanager():

secret_name = "test"
region_name = "us-west-2"
session = boto3.session.Session()
client = session.client(
    service_name='secretsmanager',
    region_name=region_name
)

try:
    get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
        SecretId=secret_name
    )
except ClientError as e:
    raise e

# Decrypts secret using the associated KMS key.
secret = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
response = json.loads(secret)
return str(response['Access Key Id']), str(response['Secret Access Key'])

SMTP_REGIONS = [
    'us-east-2',       # US East (Ohio)
    'us-east-1',       # US East (N. Virginia)
    'us-west-2',       # US West (Oregon)
    'ap-south-1',      # Asia Pacific (Mumbai)
    'ap-northeast-2',  # Asia Pacific (Seoul)
    'ap-southeast-1',  # Asia Pacific (Singapore)
    'ap-southeast-2',  # Asia Pacific (Sydney)
    'ap-northeast-1',  # Asia Pacific (Tokyo)
    'ca-central-1',    # Canada (Central)
    'eu-central-1',    # Europe (Frankfurt)
    'eu-west-1',       # Europe (Ireland)
    'eu-west-2',       # Europe (London)
    'sa-east-1',       # South America (Sao Paulo)
    'us-gov-west-1',   # AWS GovCloud (US)
]

# These values are required to calculate the signature. Do not change them.
DATE = "11111111"
SERVICE = "ses"
MESSAGE = "SendRawEmail"
TERMINAL = "aws4_request"
VERSION = 0x04

def sign(key, msg):
    return hmac.new(key, msg.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()

def calculate_key(secret_access_key, region):
    if region not in SMTP_REGIONS:
        raise ValueError("The " + region+ " Region doesn't have an SMTP endpoint.")

    signature = sign(("AWS4" + secret_access_key).encode('utf-8'), DATE)
    signature = sign(signature, region)
    signature = sign(signature, SERVICE)
    signature = sign(signature, TERMINAL)
    signature = sign(signature, MESSAGE)
    signature_and_version = bytes([VERSION]) + signature
    smtp_password = base64.b64encode(signature_and_version)
    print(smtp_password)
    return smtp_password.decode('utf-8')

def get_keys():
    accesskey, secretkey = get_secretmanager() 
    mailsecret = calculate_key(secretkey, "us-west-2")
    return accesskey, mailsecret

print(get_keys())
```

Any help is much appreciated, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of debugging i found out `bytes([VERSION])` does not work same in both python3 and python2 thats why it was returning 2 different calue for both 2 and 3
My simple fix was that to hardcode the bytes value of the hex 0x04 as `b'\x04'`

```
signature_and_version = b'\x04' + signature
```

Make sure to return the value as a string `return accesskey, str(mailsecret)` cuz in python2 it returns as a unicode.